# Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined plugman

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, plugman

I am having problem installing a custom plugin in Cordova.

```
plugman -d install --platform android --project platforms\android --plugin plugins\PrintName
```

error:

```
Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined
at C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\fetch.js:168:18
at _fulfilled (C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
at C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:509:49
at flush (C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:686:11)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

Comment: I am facing the similar error. didn't identify the actual issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue! I'll be sure to comment if I can find an answer.

Answer (score 15):

You need to specify the full plugin path, not a relative path. e.g.:

```
plugman -d install --platform android --project platforms\android --plugin "\full_path\of_your\plugins\PrintName"
```

Answer (score 11):

What I ended up having to do is uninstall plugman 2.0

```
npm remove -g plugman
```

Then I install plugman version 1.5.1

```
npm install -g plugman@1.5
```

Then I could finally add plugins to the project.

Comment: See my answer below. You need to specify the full plugin path. Not a relative path.

Comment: This worked for me (MacOSX), but why? What changed with plugman v2.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the full path for customized Cordova plugin